# View port is set in header.php but google search console giving errors

Tags: wordpress, viewport, google-search-console

I have view port set in my theme's (Astra) header.php file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

but my google serach console is showing errors related to the same. How can I solve this?
[image]

I tried placing the same code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

again into the header.php file via adding a code snippet through WPcodelite plugin. THe problem still persists?

Comment: Maybe there's a child theme overwritten your theme's header.php file, try to view the source of your page (Crtl/command + u in chrome) to check if the viewport meta tag is there

Comment: I do not use any child theme on my webisite. Checked the source of the page, the viewport meta tag is very much present.